# How to preserve new line \n with laravel sanitizer

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, sanitization

I'm trying to store text in my database with \n, so that there can be new lines whenever the admin wants. The problem I am getting is that automatically it seems laravel is sanitizing all strings that get saved to the DB. So it's saving it as \n. And then when I retrieve it (i retrieve and display with vue components not a blade file), it doesn't format it as a new line. how and what am i supposed to do. what is the right way of achieving being able to save a paragraph with new lines made with \n?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the \n to be. you can do something like this:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```